# how to call Hub or Client Method in One Signal R app1 from another One Signal R app2

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

hi i have two signalR applications and i need to call **Hub method or Client side method present** in SignalR app1 from SignalR2 app, i am using **GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext** for accessing **ChatHubIn** which present SignalR2 app:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{ 
    public void SendToOtherApp(string name, string message, string Id)
    {         
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext("ChatHubIn");
        context.Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name,message);    
    }
}
```

but i am getting error **ChatHubIn Hub could not be resolved** what is this ?? why it is coming ?? any way solve this problem or any other way to call Hub method or Client from other application.
**Edited:**

```
public class ChatHubIn : Hub
{
    public void SendToSameApp(string name, string message, string Id) //, string c_id
    {
        Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

see i have two **separate applications** **SignalR1 app**, **SignalR2 app** as i told and every body knows two apps willl have two separate client , hub parts here i need to call ChatHubIn Hub present in SignalR2 app from Hub part of SignalR1 app and from there i need to send messages to all clients in SignalR2 app

Comment: Very difficult to understand the problem by just one method... What is "ChatHubIn"? Also the best scenario for this would be self host signalR and connect the two apps.

Comment: hey thnx for reply, and "ChatHubIn" is a hub which is present in SignalR2 app and this code belongs to SignalR1 app HUb and i am trying to call "ChatHubIn".

Comment: Sorry if obvious, but does "Signalr1 app" and respectively "Signal2 app" refer to actual different versions of signalr? Or is that just you naming them?

Comment: @rdoubleui,   same version, just name is different and those are two individual signal R apps

Comment: Are they self-hosted on the same machine?

Comment: @rdoubleui, i don't know what exactly self-hosted means, but they are two different app under one server.

Comment: This leaves us with two possibilities: 1) The hub cannot be resolved because of a naming issue or 2) It cannot be established over process boundaries, for that please see my edit below.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot give you the exact answer to your problem because the short snippet of code and explanation is less than informative but what I have done is reproduced the whole solution in which I had no problems.

Just to clarify the issue:

> see i have two separate applications SignalR1 app, SignalR2 app as i
>   told and every body knows two apps willl have two separate client ,
>   hub parts here i need to call ChatHubIn Hub present in SignalR2 app
>   from Hub part of SignalR1 app and from there i need to send messages
>   to all clients in SignalR2 app

It's hard to digest the above, So what I have done is create two projects; one webform (SignalR1 which essentially the server/host) and one MVC (SignalR2 the client)

[image]

None of this was terribly difficult, The webform project I installed the full stack of signalR, I wanted it to be the server as such.

Within the MVC project I installed the SignalR JS client and the SignalR .Net client thus giving me the ability to connect to the host.

Most Importantly install/enable Cors which needs to be installed on the host:
**Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Cors -Version 5.2.3**

Allowing cors in the startup class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {

        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableJSONP = true
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

Not only can the MVC project receive messages, I now have the ability **to fire a method on the Hub**

Connecting to a host:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:45569/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
        $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:45569/signalr";
        // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
        // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
        chatHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            // Html encode display name and message. 
            var encodedName = $('<div />').text(name).html();
            var encodedMsg = $('<div />').text(message).html();
            // Add the message to the page. 
            $('#discussion').append('<li><strong>' + encodedName
                + '</strong>:&nbsp;&nbsp;' + encodedMsg + '</li>');
        };
        $.connection.hub.start(function () {
            //We can also fire back :-) Happy days
        });
    });
</script>
```

We can do this in C# too!:

```
  var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:45569/");
  IHubProxy chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("chatHub");
  hubConnection.Start().Wait();
  chatHubProxy .Invoke("Send", "name", "message");
```

Now if I install the full package of SignalR on the MVC, I could call my Hub to call another:

```
public class OtherChatHub : Hub
{ 
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {         
      var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:45569/");
      IHubProxy chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("chatHub");
      hubConnection.Start().Wait();
      chatHubProxy .Invoke("Send", "name", "message");    
    }
}
```

**//EDIT**

Due to the level of code required, to get a minimal sln working is too much for this Q. So I decided to add to GitHub for you to download and *learn* not just use the exact code.

[SignalRTwoWay-GitHub](https://github.com/TezWingfield/SignalRTwoWay)

Comment: hey thnx , can u please put full code in detail because i am new this signal R please........

Comment: @saaduu I'll sort it out later today.

Comment: @saaduu Please find download link above... Also please mark an answer as answered, if it solved the issue.

Comment: @ Tez Wingfield, sorry for very late reply, i didn't try code which u have given, bcz i have been assigned other tasks thnx alot for help and can u please put wat are all packges needed.....and i wil ask any help need, hope u wil help ..

Comment: @saaduu If you download the GitHub project it will point you in the right direction. It's only basic but will give you insight into what's going on.

Comment: @ Tez Wingfield, hey i created two projects same like, u have created and one is webapp and one Mvc and in mvc client sde i am getting error like       **ncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chatHub' of undefined**           `<script src="http://localhost:54003/signalr/hubs"></script>                                                                                                  var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;                                     $.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:54003/signalr"; ` can u please tel me why ??

Comment: On the assumption of your URLs your connecting to another app. Have you installed the JS/.Net SignalR client packages?

Comment: @saaduu GitHub packages all work...So use the MVC one and tweak as necessary. I cannot help without seeing your code.

Comment: @ Tez Wingfield, ok let me try to share my code on github.

Comment: @ Tez Wingfield, sorry i couldn't able to share on github can i get your gmail, so that i can share on Google drive....

Comment: @saaduu please take time to learn... In terms of GitHub just upload the project then I'll send a **pull request** at that point I'll fix and submit. Or you could just learn from the working solution I sent.

Comment: @ Tez Wingfield, verrryyyyyyy thnx for all your reply's, grate thank you.

Comment: @saaduu no problem at all. If you find any answer has helped fixing the problem please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more info what code is involved in order to help resolve this issue.

Please note that the two hubs have to be hosted on the same machine. If you want to address another hub in a different machine or hosting environment then have one hub act as a client to the other hub.

**Edit upon question edit:**
Just one more thing that got my attention: Based on the infos provided, that the Hub name cannot be resolved: Try to resolve the hub by calling

```
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHubIn>();
```

to debug possible naming issues that could occur when resolving the hub by name.

I'm still in doubt, that you can get hold of the `hub context` over process boundaries. If that's not possible then the cleanest approach would be to have on hub act additionally as a [hub client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client) to the other hub, which provides a specialized method to receive the notification and then broadcast it to its clients.

Comment: Not exactly in the same process. Self hosting seems fitting considering the requirements.

Comment: So you mean self-hosted (if it is) should be sufficient to get a hold of the `context`?

Comment: I assume it's not self hosted, not much detail in the Q. None of my comments are valid unless more code is supplied.

Comment: @saaduu Just out of curiosity when testing this, are you running/debugging both applications simultaneously?

Comment: @saaduu Ok, Always remember to run/debug both. Can you add all of your code to the Q?

Comment: From what I just tested, you can not get through to another hub in a different app via `GlobalHost`. I say go for the `Hub client` approach.

Comment: @ rdoubleui, yes let me try that Hub-Client approch can i get exact link about that approch insted of that Full API Guid bcz i don't know about it Please

Comment: Establish a [client connection](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#clientsetup) and then basically [call server methods using `Invoke` on the proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client#callserver)

Comment: var hubConnection = new HubConnection("MyWebApi");
            IHubProxy applicationHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
            applicationHubProxy.Invoke("MyMethod", AnyParams); As @rdoubleui as already stated just a little digging into docs.